# How to add HTML elements to AngularUI calendar

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar

I/m working with `AngularUI calendar`.My task is **add some data to `Calendar cells` with CSS Styles**.

I haven't any idea about that,beacause I'm new to `AngularJS`.

Please help me.

Thanks.

**My Angular Code**

```
$scope.uiConfig = {
    calendar: {
        height: 500,
        editable: true,
        header: {
            left: '',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'prev next'
        },
        defaultView: 'month'

    }
};
```

Comment: Please add your Angular Controller coding to get some idea.

Comment: ok, is your calendar view display correctly.Please check any console errors found or not.

Comment: Calendar view is successfully viewing and there is no any errors in console

Comment: Please refer my answer I'm sure you can do your task with my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this kind of effort with **dayRender function**. You can add html elements to your calendar using **cell.html**

With my answer all cells fill with same styles and other HTML Elements.Then you can customize it with your back-end array.

**Try this**

```
$scope.uiConfig = {
    calendar: {
        height: 500,
        editable: true,
        header: {
            left: '',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'prev next'
        },
        defaultView: 'month',
        dayRender: function (date, cell) {
                 $r = $scope.getDateInfo(date);
                if($r){
                   cell.css("background-color", "#e6f7ff"); 
                }
                cell.html('<b>'+$r.amount+'</b>');
            }

    }
};

$scope.getDateInfo = function(date){
    return {
             amount : 50000
            } 

}
```

You can add in-line styles or classes to HTML elements.

In this I used another function.Please refer my code and any further matter simply leave a comment.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kvakulo/CYnJY/4/)

Cheers!!

Comment: how can I add styles or css classes to that.its not clear to me

Comment: you can classes like this `'<b class="euro amount_font">'+$r.amount+'</b>'`

Comment: ok great.only one doubt.What's the way to add another HTML element to this, I tried but its wrong.

Comment: you can do it like this `'<b class="euro amount_font">'+$r.amount+'</b>'+'<i class="fa fa-eur euro marginLeft5"></i>'`